# Stats: Probability of Sequence given Binomial distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I'm trying to find a function in numpy that gives the probability of observing a sequence given an initial binomial probability distribution.

For example, if the sequence was [H, T, H, T, H, T, H, T] and H both had 0.5 probabilities, is there a function that will give the low probability of observing these counts of H and T (order doesn't matter)?

I was trying to follow the example in the numpy documentation, but my code below is giving a very low probability (5.8%) when it should be near 50%: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html#numpy.random.binomial

```
import numpy as np

p_H = 0.5
p_T = 1 - p_H

seq = ['H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T']

num_H = seq.count('H')

p_obs = sum(np.random.binomial(num_H, p_H, 1000)==num_H)/1000

print('Probability of observing', num_H, 'H:',p_obs)
```

I imagine I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any typos in the sentence "...and H both had 0.5 probabilities, is there a function that will give the low probability of observing..."? What does "low probability" mean? The question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compute the probability of an observed value of k successes given n trials with independent success probability p as:

```
   choose(n, k) * p**k * (1-p)**(n-k)
```

which is the probability mass function of the binomial distribution. It is also available via

```
   binom.pmf(k)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The answer you're getting is the chance of getting 4 in a row - or about 6% (4 taken 4 over 1000 samples with p = 0.5)

What you want is: `p_obs = sum(np.random.binomial(len(seq), p_H, 1000)==num_H)/1000`

Comment: Ah I see - ok so that was an answer to a different problem. Thank you.